# Microsoft Security Essentials says phantomjs for Windows has Varpes.M!plock virus

Tags: anti-virus, malware, phantomjs

I can scan the zip file phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip, and it does not remove anything. But once I unzip the exe, Security Essentials remove the phantomjs.exe.
The zip has the correct MD5 checksum. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detection looks to be a false positive. A sample of the file has been submitted to Microsoft.

See the following links for more information:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/microsoft-security-essentials-says-phantomjs-for/475ade4e-1b42-427d-acac-e954047d3883?auth=1

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/f8Ea19KmQ3c